# Google Compute Engine: Caching when running Builds on Preemptible VMs

Tags: jenkins, caching, google-compute-engine

We just migrated our Jenkins builds from a build agent running 24/7 to use GCE Preemtible VMs via the [google-compute-engine-plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/google-compute-engine-plugin).

Now our builds take much longer, because all builds need to resolve all dependencies (Docker Images, Maven Artifacts, NPM Packages, etc.) almost every time. The Caching on the VM is no longer effective, because the VMs are stopped after a couple of minutes.

Is there a quick solution or a best practice for this that works for the different use cases (Docker, Maven, NPM)?

For example

- can I enable a Proxy or CDN that is "closer" (in terms of network latency) to the VMs in the Google Cloud?
- Or would mounting a bucket for persisting the Images, local Maven Repo and NPM Cache speed things up?
- Any other ideas?

Comment: CDN would cache HTTP(S) load balanced content so not sure whether its a right fit for your use case or not. Proxy could be a possible workaround in terms of latency but it may also depend on your design and use case. However, I was looking at [this](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Google+Cloud+Build+Plugin) where they advised to use Google Cloud Storage (GCS). If you use GCS at the same region as VM, it seems would help speed up the process. Have you tried GCS?

Comment: @RahiR Using GCS seems to match my "mounting a bucket ..." approach. I haven't tried it, yet. It's good to know that there is a Jenkins plugin for it. OTOH I'd rather mount the bucket into the GCE Image (instead of the Jenkins job), because editing every single build Job to use GCS as a cache would cause a lot of effort. A global (not build job related) solution (such as Proxy/CDN) would be much easier to implement.

Comment: Not sure what you meant by mounting bucket into the GCE image. You can mount a bucket with GCE instances using Cloud Storage [FUSE](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gcs-fuse). However, the solution you are looking at using Proxy/CDN, you can file a feature request [here](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers).

Comment: If your real problem is that your instance is being preempted before completing the task, this means Google is resource limited. Pick a different machine type (larger instance) or change regions. Also consider using standard instances (not preemptible). Best practice: create machine images that have everything you need to minimize download / installation setup. If this is not possible to implement then preemptible instances might not be a good use case for you.

Answer (score 0):

CDN would cache HTTP(S) load balanced content so not sure whether its a right fit for your use case or not. Proxy could be a possible workaround in terms of latency but it may also depend on your design and use case. However, I was looking at [this](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Google+Cloud+Build+Plugin) where they advised to use Google Cloud Storage (GCS). If you use GCS at the same region as VM, it seems would help speed up the process.